# Export and Import of partitioned table

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have tables which are partitioned, with monthly interval, on one database center. I am going to export these partitioned tables and import them into another database center.

Will these imported tables in second datacenter generate partition names on a monthly basis?

Comment: It may depend on which tools you use.  With traditional `exp` and `imp`, probably no; with the newer `expdp` and `impdp`, probably yes.

Comment: May also depend on whether the tables already exist on the second database, if so whether they are already partitioned, and if so how the existing partitioning is defined.

Comment: Just adding to @AlexPoole's point-- you say that the table is partitioned "with monthly interval".  If you mean that you have interval partitioned tables rather than range-partitioned tables where each partition has a 1 month range, the answer may well be different.